# How to get Google+ page id as integer?

Tags: api, google-plus

I need to create an app and my plus page id isn't in integer but in my name. I've hovered on the date stamp as instructed by a support here but still showing my +name. How can I get my plus page id in integer? Google is simply not educating people on this!

Comment: See if [the following](http://www.cabanova.com/help/Knowledgebase/Article/View/971/196/how-do-i-find-my-google-plus-page-id-google) helps.

Comment: Ok, now I created a new page for the app I'm planning to integrate on my site and the integer was generated.Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get) to get a Google+ page/profile ID.

Enter the string name for `userId` e.g. `+GoogleDevelopers` and for `fields` enter `id`.

[image]